# beginner GNU Makefile Error

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my first, attempt at a, Makefile after necessity from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834500/multiple-functions-definition-errors).

Anyway here's the code

```
SortLab.exe : SelectionSort.o Main.o  
        g++ -o $@ $^  
SelectionSort.o : SelectionSort.cpp SelectionSort.h  
Main.o : Main.cpp  

#-------------------------------------------------------------

run: SortLab.exe  
        ./SortLab.exe  

clean:  
    rm -f *.o  
    rm -f *.exe  

build: clean SortLab.exe  

%.o: %.cpp  
    g++ -c $<
```

I intend to have `SelectionSort.cpp` & `SelectionSort.h` form an object file, and `Main.cpp` to form its own object file. Then finally create an executable. `Main.cpp` depends on `SelectionSort.cpp`, where do I go wrong?

Also where can I find what the different `GNU` commands mean, `-o` `-c` and such

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: I second the previous comment, but the first thing I'd check is whether every indented thing has a tab character before it with no spaces. It's probably the most common error in Makefiles, especially for beginners.

Comment: I can't believe one source module depends on another. You probably want to have the object file depend on the header. Also, the options can be found in the GCC manual at http://gcc.gnu.org.

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't need to define the `%.o: %.cpp` rule yourself, Make knows how to compile C++.
2. Indent with tabs, not spaces; Make is sensitive to the difference.
3. Every object file should depend on the headers included in the source files it depends on. You probably need `Main.o : Main.cpp  SelectionSort.h`.
4. `build` shouldn't depend on `clean`, it defeats one of Make's main features (selectively recompilation when files have changed).
5. If you make `build` the first target, you can run Make without a target to get a full compile. It's customary to call the main target `all`.

Comment: For Point 3. If Main.cpp depends on SelectionSort.cpp, which includes SelectionSort.h would I still need that line "Main.o : Main.cpp SelectionSort.h."?

Comment: @Malaken, as noted above, one source file can't possibly depend on another (unless you have something crazy like #include "SelectionSort.cpp" there). @larsmans, the default target is the first one, how it is named is irrelevant, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Malaken: modules should never depend on each other. Dependency of X on Y in Make means: to compile X, we need to first compile Y. Let the modules depend only on the headers.

Comment: SelectionSort.cpp holds a class, SelectionSort, that I use in main.cpp.

Comment: @Malaken: classes should be declared in headers. What else is in `SelectionSort.h`?

Comment: @Malaken, that only means that main.cpp depends on the class definition, which is probably in the SelectionSort.h (if it's not, it should be moved there or it can't be correctly used by other units anyway). The definitions of member functions and static member variables in the SelectionSort.cpp can be changed freely without any need to recompile other units, as long as the class definition in the header isn't changed. That's precisely one of the reasons why it's better to define member functions in the *.cpp files rather then in the headers.